# Как сделать чтобы выводил текущий месяц

Tags: javascript

```js
function createDate(){
  var date = new Date;
  var year = date.getFullYear();
  var month = date.getMonth()-1;
  var numberDate = date.getDate();
  var calendar = document.getElementById('calendar');
  var createElement = document.createElement('span');
  createElement.appendChild(document.createTextNode('Узнать дату'))
  calendar.insertBefore(createElement, calendar.firstChild)
  calendar.addEventListener('click', function(){
    createElement.textContent = year + ' ' + '0' + month + ' ' + numberDate;
  });
};

createDate();
```

```html
<div id="calendar"></div>
```

Comment: Самый простой вариант: `new Date().toLocaleString('ru', {month: 'long' });` а иначе сделать массив месяцев и выводить через номер месяца.

Comment: если нужно числовое значение, то ошибка у вас тут `var month = date.getMonth()-1;` тут должно быть `+1`, т.е вот так `var month = date.getMonth()+1;`

Comment: @ЕвгенийНиколаев, проблему он решил моим примером, просто `комменты со спасибо` не приветствуются и он был удален.

Comment: @And окей) главное вопрос решен)

Comment: @Евгений Николаев Здравствуйте сейчас 03 месяц прибавить 1 получится 04, а должно 05

Comment: @Leks вы не правы, `date.getMonth()` вернет вам `4`, после этого от этого числа вы вычитаете `1`, получаете 3, что и выводите в ответ потом.

Comment: @Евгений Николаев  Извините Вы правы я ошибся

Comment: @Leks `0` нужно добавлять лишь для месяцев с 1 по 9, а не для всех подряд. Для этого можно дописать такую функцию `function addingZero(n){return (n < 10) ? ('0' + n) : ('' + n);}` и использовать вот так `addingZero(month)`